# Django Middleware Login Required

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am trying to implement site wide login restriction based on information found [here](http://onecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware):

I have created the `login_required_middleware.py` in:

```
/home/user/projects/test/test/
```

I have added the following to my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in `settings.py`

```
'test.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
```

When I refresh in my browser, I receive the error:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

Where do I go next?

Comment: I have also tried:

    'test.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',

Comment: Set DEBUG=True, and post the traceback you get here.

Comment: It is, that's the only message that's returned.

Comment: Okay, then you must have a reverse proxy up front (Apache, nginx, etc) that's actually causing the error. Try running the site with `python manage.py runserver`, just to verify it works fine like that, but most likely you have a config issue on your webserver.

Comment: This was simply lack of understanding of python paths on my part.  I've renamed the file and fixed the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES line and it is now functioning properly.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it when you can (couple of days).

Comment: Also, as an aside, if you are using Apache and don't get any errors on screen or in admin email when DEBUG=True, you can check the Apache error logs. If it is a server-side error that prevents Django from notifying admins, often they are in the logs on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because it's not finding your middleware. Make sure your middleware is in the python path of your project.

for example if the name of your middleware is `login_required_middleware.py`
you should put it in the directory of manage.py or in any subdirectory.

then in settings.py in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` you should call it like

```
'login_required_middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware'
```